# How to search beacons using UUID using altbeacon android library?

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

The alt beacon library is providing many examples based on the beacon layout. No documentation on how to find the beacons using the uuid?

Tried with the code;

```
try {
    beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));

    Identifier identifier = Identifier.parse("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"); //beacon 1
    beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("identifier", identifier, null, null));
} catch (RemoteException e) {    }
```

It doesn't work. But the equivalent one using the native APIs works fine.

```
List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<>();
ParcelUuid uid = ParcelUuid.fromString(J_UUID);
ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(uid).build();
scanFilters.add(filter);

List<ScanFilter> filters = scanFilters;
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("o-scan", true);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filters, settings, pendingIntent);
```

Any help is appreciated achieving the same using the alt beacon library so that I don't need to worry about the scheduling of jobs repeatedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't confuse a 128-bit Bluetooth GATT service UUID with a beacon's Proximity UUID.** Both superficially look similar when represented as hex digits separated by dashes, and have the same number of bytes, but the two have fundamentally different purposes and ways of using them with various APIs:

A **Proximity UUID** is a BLE beacon concept.  It is the first beacon identifier that represents an organisation's ownership of the beacon and is typically used to filter for beacons with that belong to you.  It is used with iBeacon and AltBeacon formats (In AltBeacon it is often called ID1).  This field is encoded inside a BLE **manufacturer advertisement**

A **GATT Service UUID** is a lower-level BLE concept that represents a particular functionsl service a BLE peripheral performs (e.g. a heart rate monitor). Custom services are typically advertised with 128 bit GATT Service UUIDs encoded inside a **GATT service advertisement**, the which is completely different type of BLE advertising packet than the manufacturing advertisements described above.  While these service advertisement packets are used for Eddystone beacons, Eddystone formats use a much shorter 16-bit GATT Service UUID to advertise themselves, and the actual beacon identifier is inside of their data payload.

The second code example in  the question shows how to use Android's built in BlE APIs to find a device advertising a 128-bit GATT Service UUID.  Standard beacon formats do not use such structures, which is why the Android Beacon Library is not designed to easily search for these packets.  It is a specialized library for working with BLE beacons, not a more general BLE library.  This is why the first code example does not work.

There are several reasons standard beacon formats do not work with 128-bit GATT Service UUIDs:

1. Packets are very limited in size and a 128-bit GATT Service UUID takes up so much room that very little remains.
2. A beacon format must have a preamble byte pattern which identifies that the packet uses that format. If the   128-bit GATT Service UUID is used as a beacon identifier, there is no configurable preamble before this that can be used to identify the beacon format.

Some beacons that use standard formats like iBeacon, AltBeacon or Eddystone  interleave more than one advertisement, and a 128 bit GATT Service UUID may be included in one of these, typically to advertise a proprietary service for configuring the beacon.  If you have a hardware beacon that does this, do not confuse this advertisement with an actual beacon packet.  This advertisement should be used only to access the proprietary configuration service.

Comment: Wondering whether I could use it to scan the BLE devices in general so that no need to worry about the scheduling, etc. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You could absolutely do this, but it is a bit kludgy.  You'd have to set up a custom beacon format (similar to Eddystone-UID)  to match the start of the service UUID.  The matching expression is limited to 2 bytes, so you'd have to use the beacon format to match the the first two bytes of the service UUID then put the remaining bytes into an identifier field and monitor for a Region that matches the remaining bytes of the service UUID

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The second part of the code works fine in many 8.0 devices except S9. Did you face any similar issues?

Comment: While I have tested the Android Beacon Library on the S9 without trouble, I did not do explicit tests to verify that the equivalent code shown in the second half of your question actually returns results.  I am unaware of problems, but have not gone looking for them.